# <Include/>Tag getting cut off in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to create an xml layout that looks like this [Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkRhk.png).
But from the below code I am getting a clipped of version of the image which is shown in this image.[Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iDn6.png). As summary section is getting clipped out of the screen.
Can someone help me to get the desired result? I have attached the current code of the layout below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ai.edbox.teacher.UI.Activity.MyClassesActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backbutton_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_back"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.024"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Classes"
            tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/backbutton_imageview"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.168"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <!--<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/class_list_layout"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>>
    </HorizontalScrollView>-->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myclasses_assignment_tab"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_timetable" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Assignments"
                    android:textSize="9.3sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myclasses_classtest_tab"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_timetable" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="9.3sp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Class Tests" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myclasses_attendance_tab"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_timetable" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="9.3sp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Attendance" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myclasses_timetable_tab"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_timetable" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="9.3sp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Time Table" />
            </LinearLayout>-->




        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentPlaceHolder"
                >
                <include
                    layout="@layout/fragment_display_attendance"/>

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share layout of fragment_display_attendance

Comment: try to set width and height to fragment _display _attendance  layout inside include tag.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Actually I want to load whatever inside the include in fragment dynamically.

Comment: @ysl Find the file here. https://pastebin.com/v9zJG3PJ

Comment: @MohammedFarhan Setting width also doesnt help. View gets clipped. https://ibb.co/iNefMk at width 200dp

Comment: I got it. It was because of the fixed Horizontal bias in one of the constraint layout. Thank you for your help